# Validad variable blade Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo el código el cual obtiene el valor de la variable $direccion y lo escribe en el input, pero mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna forma mas limpia con Blade de comprobar si la variable $direccion contiene algo?

```
  @if(isset($direccion))
    {{Form::text('direccion',$direccion, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
  @else
    {{Form::text('direccion',$direccion=null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
  @endif
```

No deseo repetir veces esto:

```
    {{Form::text('direccion',$direccion, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Comment: Pues opciones tienes, por ejemplo *empty*

Comment: Lo que no quiero es repetir veces esto:       {{Form::text('direccion',$direccion, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}

Comment: no uses laravel collectivee, blade tiene formas mas limpias de hacer esto

Comment: {{Form::text('direccion',$direccion ?? $direccion : 'null', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}